# How can I locate the check boxes in JFreeChart?

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart, jcombobox, jcheckbox

I am trying to locate checkboxes in JFreeChart and also I want to manage them in a combo box. How can I locate them and then how can I make them in combo box?

My checkboxes look like this:

[image]

As I said before I want to show them in a combo box at the upper left of the chart. My code looks like this:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i< dataIndex; i++)
{
    JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox( new VisibleAction(name,renderer,i));
    checkBox.setSelected(true);
    renderer.setSeriesVisible(i,true);
    controlPanel.add(checkBox);
    checkBox.setFont(controlPanelFont);
}
```

Comment: The official Java tutorial on combo boxes is quite helpful: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html

Comment: Are the checkboxes part of the chart? Are they part of the chart legend? Or are they `JCheckBox`es?

Comment: They are part of the chart. @Abra

Comment: `JCheckBox` is _not_ part of `JFreeChart`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjfreechart%5D+JComboBox). For more specific help, please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that shows your revised approach..